# How to execute a function after the modal is loaded?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to execute a function on the `Bootstrap` modal after opening it. At the moment I found in the doc the following event: `show.bs.modal`.

I tried to bind to the modal this:

```
$('#my-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
   alert(true);
});
```

the problem is that the `alert` is displayed before the opening of the modal.

Is there any way to call a function after the modal opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should help:

```
$('#my-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
   alert(true);
});
```

Just change show to shown.